# KDB+/Q: How does one select all items (keys+values) of a dictionary where the respective value conforms to a condition?

Tags: kdb

How does one filter the items of a dictionary based on the values therein.
For instance, given the following dictionary:

```
990.5| 0
900.5| 0
600.5| 300
600  | -300
```

How does one filter out all instances therein where the value = 0.
The result thereafter being:

```
600.5| 300
600  | -300
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

```
q)d: 990.5 900.5 600.5 600 ! 0 0 300 -300
q)k ! d k: where d <> 0
600.5| 300
600  | -300
```

Answer (score 5):

The where keyword can also be used to achieve this without assignment

```
q)d:990.5 900.5 600.5 600!0 0 300 -300
q)where[d<>0]#d
```